# how to Prevent Future Builder form multiple callings

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-futurebuilder

I use from Future Builder to get some of my needed data like images for my  listview but the getimage functaion called multiple times, how coud i prevent it?
the getimage functaion is called from build i know its  wrong but i must pass the carUserId to function and i cant pass it if i call get image
outside the build so what shoud i do?

> i called getimage function in initState but it didn't solve my problem in this way the images are not appears at all

heare is my code

my getimage function

```
  Future<String> getimage(carUserId) async {
    var res = await carobj.getAdData(carUserId);
    return (res.data() as Map)['imgPro'].toString();
  }
```

I get image heare:

```
 child: FutureBuilder<String>(
                      future: _imageFuture,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Container(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg",
                                        scale: 0.9),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                          );
                        } else {
                          String usersImg = snapshot.data.toString();
                          return Container(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        usersImg != null
                                            ? (usersImg)
                                            : ("https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg"),
                                        scale: 0.9),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                          );
                        }
                      }),
```

my list widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 Widget? showCarsList() {

  if (cars != null) {


    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cars!.docs.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        carUserId = (cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['uId'];
        _mFuture = getNumber();
        _imageFuture = getimage(carUserId);
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: FutureBuilder<String>(
                      future: _imageFuture,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Container(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg",
                                        scale: 0.9),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                          );
                        } else {
                          String usersImg = snapshot.data.toString();
                          return Container(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        usersImg != null
                                            ? (usersImg)
                                            : ("https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg"),
                                        scale: 0.9),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                          );
                        }
                      }),
                ),
                title: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Text((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['username']
                      .toString()),
                ),
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['carLocation'] !=
                          null)
                          ? Text(
                          (cars!.docs[index].data()
                          as Map)['carLocation'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)))
                          : Text("unknown",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6))),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 4.0,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.location_pin,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: (cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['uId'] == userId
                    ? Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onDoubleTap: () {},
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
                    : Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Image.network((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['urlImage']!=null
                    ? ((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['urlImage'].toString()): ("https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text('\$'+(cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['carPrice'].toString()
                  ,style:TextStyle(fontFamily: "oleo",letterSpacing: 2,
                      fontSize: 24) ,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['carModel'].toString(),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text(tAgo.format((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['time'].toDate()),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ],),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),

              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15,bottom: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.brush_outlined),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['carColor'].toString()),
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    FutureBuilder(  future: _mFuture,
                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            String userNumbers = snapshot.data.toString();
                            return Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.phone_android),
                                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  child: Align(
                                    child: Text(userNumbers.toString()),
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  ),
                                ),  ],
                            );
                          }else{
                            return Text("loading");

                          }

                        }
                    )



                  ],
                ),

              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15),
                child: Text((cars!.docs[index].data() as Map)['description'].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)
                  ),),

              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,)
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }else{
    return Text('Loading.....');
  }

}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )),
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )),
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.login_outlined,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ))
    ],
    flexibleSpace: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blueAccent, Colors.redAccent])),
    ),
    title: Text("home page"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: showCarsList(),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    tooltip: 'add post',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      showDialogForAddingData();
    },
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Call getimage inside ListView must call multiple times. Since it's loop through all lists and get image from it. 
A single image is hitting multiple times is that what are you asking?

Comment: yes the list items have difrents images but every items image is set agien and agien

Comment: how many time single image is hitting?

Comment: when i scroll to new item and go back to previous one images change from place holder image to user image so every time i scroll this happens once